# Using lodash 'throttle' with mousemove event

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a mousemove event listener, and the goal is to only trigger the function inside of it every 100ms. I found the [lodash throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) function would fit my needs, but I'm having a hard time implementing it. Here's my code so far

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  console.log(e);
  _.throttle(test, 100);
});

function test() {
  console.log('test');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

and the jsfiddle with the lodash library:

http://jsfiddle.net/c56ebw9d/5/

Any ideas why the event log triggers, but my test log won't trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_.throttle()` will return a new throttled function, which then need to be invoked for every event. Tweaked your code a bit:

```js
var throttleFn =  _.throttle(test, 1000);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', throttleFn);

function test() {
  console.log('test');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: great! the second one seems to work best for me. thanks!

Comment: Tweaked your code a bit - the 1st answer was actually incorrect. You've got to call the same function returned by `_.throttle()` every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding this when working with React, then I found out that the throttled function should remain the same between re-renderings, meaning we have to use React's UseCallback function. This works by changing this:

```
_.throttle(test, 100);
```

To:

```
useCallback(_.throttle(test, 100));
```